# Can you list all Java projects held in a ClearCase component?

Tags: clearcase

I wish to script the following function.

1. accept a [ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_ClearCase) stream name
2. list all the modifiable components associated with this stream
3. list all the Java projects owned by each modifiable ClearCase component

I have managed 1 and 2 above using `cleartool` commands.

I am now stuck as to how to list all the Java projects owned by each modifiable ClearCase component.

If it helps (or I could use this some how in the solution), the Java projects are all created in [IBM Rational Application Developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Application_Developer), so there are one or more `.project` files contained in each ClearCase component.

How might I complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An UCM component is just a set of files within one common root (either a Vob itself for a "Vob component", or one of the Vob direct subdirectories).

That means once you have found the right components, all you need to do is to search for the `.project` files within said components.
A simple [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) should be enough.